# How to make a link open a new window when clicked in JavaScript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I'm making a small web app in java script, it's a simple app to create bookmarks and save websites. I have made this web app so it saves links to websites, but I don't know how to make this links clickable and secondly make them open then following link in a new browser window.

this is my code :

```
<form class="ui stacked segment form" action="/bookmark/{{bookmark.id}}/addwebsite" method="POST">
  <div class="two fields">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Title</label>
      <input placeholder="Title" type="text" name="title">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Link</label>
      <input placeholder="Link" type="link" name="link">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Summary</label>
      <input placeholder="Summary" type="text" name="summary">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="ui blue submit button">Add Website</button>
</form>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<table class="ui table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Website</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Summary</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each bookmark.websites}}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{title}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{link}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{summary}}
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="/bookmark/{{../bookmark.id}}/deletewebsite/{{id}}" class="ui icon button">
            <i class="icon trash"></i>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the link be clickable as it is already? First part of question doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

Add `target="_blank"` attribute to your anchor tags. This will open links in the new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Using `target="_blank"`will solve the problem for you

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="blank"` like this

```
<a href="/bookmark/{{../bookmark.id}}/deletewebsite/{{id}}" target="blank" class="ui icon button">click</a>
```